# What is a polite way of talking about a recently-deceased person?

Tags: expressions, politeness, expression-choice

In my language (Arabic), we say things that can be translated to:

- Mr X, God have mercy on him, was ..
- Mr X, God puts him in heaven, was. . . .
- Mr X, God forgive him, was. . . .

How does one talk about a recently-deceased person in English in similar terms?

Comment: Another version from _algerian_ arabic we use is: 'Mr X, may God's have mercy for him, did..' 'الله يرحمو'

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces, it's just "rest in peace"

Comment: Off-topic, but إن شاءالله‎ is typically romanized as Insha'Allah or Inshallah.

Comment: Not an answer to this question, but in Hebrew the common phrase is "*zichrono l'vracha*", which means "may his memory be a blessing".

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The phrase you are looking for is "may he rest in peace".  "Robin Williams, may he rest in peace, was..."

The phrase "God put him in Heaven" would sound charmingly exotic.  The person you are speaking to would likely have never heard it before, and your sentiment would sound all the more touching and sincere for its unfamiliarity.

"God forgive him" implies you think he did something terribly, terribly wrong.  The clear implication (to a native English speaker) is "may God forgive him *because I won't*."

Comment: Another common one is “God rest his soul” (mostly used in Ireland, perhaps?).

Comment: Ireland?  I would have guessed it was translated from the Yiddish.

Comment: **"rest in peace** is much more common than **"may he rest in peace"**.

Comment: @Joe I have to disagree with that. I've heard “may he rest in peace” in this context many, many times, but never just “rest in peace”. I've heard “bless her soul” with no overt subject, but that doesn't necessarily refer to dead people: “My grandmother, bless her soul, is/was the kindest person I've ever known” works equally well in present and past tense.

Comment: @Malvolio Is it a Yiddish expression? My comment about Ireland was only based on a vague feeling of associating the phrase with an Oirish brogue—it may well be quite coincidental.

Comment: hey janus!  as an **interruption** to a sentence: it's "rest in peace". As a stand-alone phrase in some context, may "he rest in peace". "Did you know that as well as being a famous astronaut Gordon Cooper - rest in peace - believed in UFOs and was an activist in that field?"

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet -- my feeling that it was Yiddish was entirely based on the same vague sense.  "Mrs. Bronstein upstead -- may she rest in peace -- always with the *kvetching*."

Comment: @Joe That was exactly the context I meant. I have never heard anyone use “rest in peace” without “may (s)he” used as interruption to a sentence. I’m sure it does occur, but I cannot recall ever hearing it: I have only heard, “Did you know that Gordon Cooper—may he rest in peace—believed in UFOs?”.

Comment: JBJ - fair enough!  It could be a regional/age/etc thing, you know

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet when talking about one's grandmother, you can bless her cotton socks too. Perhaps a local thing but people say that more often than bless her soul where I am :)

Comment: "May God have mercy on his soul"...

Comment: @jammy Very true; but blessing someone's (cotton) socks rules out the possibility of it being a dead person—that one is only used for the living.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it is not Yiddish. Malvolio thought it might be in his comment (not in his answer). RIP is 'Rest in Peace' in English, but was 'Requiescat in pace' before that. It can be found on 10th century Christian and Jewish gravestones. When saying "Mr. XYZ, may he rest in peace..." the speaker would sometimes cross herself if Roman Catholic. There are references to that in 19th century literature. There isn't an exclusively Christian connotation though, as Jews and other faiths use the same expression without making the sign of the cross. This is a good answer! It is truly ecumenical.

Comment: @EllieKesselman (Just saw your comment now) — I was talking specifically about the “God rest his soul” version which has a bit of an Irish twang in my head, whether purely by cerebral oddity or because it is actually mostly used in Ireland. “May he rest in peace” is of course quite universal (and can be found on Christian and Jewish gravestones even earlier than the 10th century—it goes at least back to the sixth, probably farther).

Answer (score 85):

The previous answers are well and good, but you can also be respectful when talking about a recently-deceased person by referring to them simply as:

> "The late Mr. Smith..."

This is a formal (and thus, respectful) indication that Mr. Smith has recently passed away, and also avoids any reference to religion, in case others might take offense or discomfort.

Comment: First thanks for the word 'late' +1 . i want to note additionnaly that even non-religious people may mention God in their emotional phrases as acquired from culture and society. I personally know an atheist who said once "الله يرحمو".

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces: sure they do sometimes, in English it's quite common since we have so many colloquialisms invented by Christians. But as an atheist I generally try to avoid bringing God into *sincere* speech since it would be inauthentic even if it's perfectly normal idiomatic English. Unless God is what I'm talking about, of course, as in this comment! And I try to avoid bringing God into *insincere* speech such as jokes, around people who would (quite reasonably) be offended by my irreverence. Don't always succeed, of course.

Comment: (In truth, he hadn't died, but he never could make it to dinner on time, which often meant that Mrs. Smith would wish that he was, in fact, late. Though perhaps, knowing the circumstances, he would not just be late, but rather he would be "late late".)

Comment: @cwallenpoole He probably also always wished that he wasn't mistaken for a woman (or she wasn't mistaken for a man?  Hard to tell from your comment which way it is...).

Comment: @Doc cwallenpoole's comment introduces a new character, the late Mr. Smith's exasperated wife. It's a bit of off-topic humour, but no gender-bending is involved.

Comment: As an atheist, I'm quite comfortable saying "may his soul rest in peace" or "may God rest his soul" in English. Similarly, in Arabic, I usually use "الله يرحمو" (may God have mercy on him). The only exception is when I'm addressing a person who is an atheist himself. Personally, I don't like to bring up my "religiono-politics" in such sensitive times. If the other person feels better when I mention God (if they're religious, they most certainly will), then I see no reason why I wouldn't.

Comment: The (non-)religious aspects have been covered in the other comments but I wonder if there's not also a slight difference in tone, here? Referring to "the late Mr Smith" seems mostly intended to convey the information that Mr Smith died recently, whereas something like "may God rest his soul" seems to convey praise to the person, too.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Anecdotal, but in my experience, "late" can be used to refer to someone for quite some time after they die.

Comment: There's generally less need for politeness when somebody is long dead. Neither "The late Julius Ceasar" nor "Julias Ceasar, may God rest his soul" are likely to be used (except ironically)

Comment: If nothing else, using the simple "late" descriptor is less of a mouthful.

Comment: @Doc, Was trying to convey the idea that Mrs. Smith would make Mr. Smith late late if he was late.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to retain the use of the word "God" you could use the following:

> "Mr. Smith, God rest his soul, ..."

Answer (score 15):

The question is entitled 'Polite way of talking about a person recently dead.' Certainly in British English, references to religion are best avoided unless in a specifically religious context.

It would be usual to say either 'the late Mr X' or 'the recently deceased Mr X.'

Comment: "Dear departed" is another, more affectionate variant of this form, e.g. ["Our dear departed John F. Kennedy"](http://context.reverso.net/traduzione/inglese-italiano/dear+departed)

Comment: @user568458 That is well understood, but not common, in Britain and would sound slightly uncomfortable in a largely secular community.

Answer (score 8):

In English, the following are all in reasonably common use.

- The Late ...
- The late lamented ...
- He will be missed
- The sadly missed ...
- The sorely missed ...
- Rest in peace, ...
- May he rest in peace
- May his soul rest in peace
- God rest his soul in peace
- God rest his soul
- God rest him
- God rest him and keep him as his own
- God Rest him and keep him

The meaning is clear, you will miss the deceased, and wish him peace, rest, and to be with God.

Answer (score 6):

A common way to respectfully refer to a deceased person is [of blessed memory](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/of_blessed_memory)

> Used respectfully in reference to a dead person:
>
> "a gracious lady of blessed memory" (from [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/blessed))

or

> "Mr. Smith of blessed memory"

It even has it's own acronym [OBM](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/OBM) - generally used in writing.

> "Mr. Smith OBM."

Answer (score 2):

My preference is to refer to a deceased person as if they're still a person, just in the past tense. For example, my grandmother was a wonderful woman, but had many challenges in her life. It's the keeping-the-memory-alive reference style.

I think adding anything involving "resting" in "peace" shows a strong religous bias. (Being Christian, this doesn't offend me, but might turn others off, especially if they have begun questioning their believes as part of the grieving process) If I *must* include a phrase when referring to a specific deceased person, I would probably have to choose "the late".

Answer (score 2):

In general, secular nations don't use the "God" phrases outside formal or ceremonial situations. If the recently deceased was not known to you personally you simply call them "late" plus past tense: "The late Joan Rivers / Robin Williams was .....". If you are writing something, simple past tense without honorifics is standard. See Wikipedia for many, many examples.

Even England, with its strong Christian history, makes its most important official pronouncement with no reference to any religion: "The King is dead. Long live the King."

Ben's lengthy list would be fine in a speech, most commonly at the person's funeral. Many of those terms would sound rather pompous elsewhere.

I like "Mr X, God puts him in heaven, was..." - it has a pleasant far-away-land feel to it.

"Mr X, God's have mercy for him, " is a bit too close to "May God have mercy on your soul" - a phrase to AVOID at all costs. It was often spoken by the priest or judge just before the condemned person's execution, the unspoken second part being "because we won't."